# Difference between: Economics SE vs Money SE vs Quantitative Finance SE

Tags: discussion

I don't understand the boundaries between this sites. I don't have sufficient background in these topics to even try to come with hypothesis, I know it seems I'm not putting effort, but I don't know the answer.

I'm trying to understand the difference between this sites, they clearly have a lot in common, I can find questions about stock prices in all three, this is the amount of results of the word "stock":

-[Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/)                375

-[Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/)                    5,865

-[Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/) 2,489

Comment: Have you compared the opening statements in the Tour of each?

Comment: @Santropedro, agreed ... clearer lines like [this Computer Science demarcation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) would be great to have...

Answer (score 3):

https://economics.stackexchange.com/tour says:

> **Economics Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for professional and academic economists and analysts.

https://money.stackexchange.com/tour says:

> **Money Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for people who want to be financially literate.

https://quant.stackexchange.com/tour says:

> **Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for professionals and academics in quantitative finance.

**Money** appears to be the only site of the three that would be welcoming to home users interested in money.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_finance) says:

> Mathematical finance, also known as **quantitative finance**, is a
>   field of applied mathematics, concerned with financial markets.

This suggests to me that **Quantitative Finance** is the more specialized of the two sites for professionals and academics in the vicinity of money and that **Economics** probably caters for the remainder of topics in the vicinity of money.

However, the best way to be clear on the scope of any site, if not clear from its Tour or Help/On-topic pages, is to ask on its per-site Meta.